# Geometry representation of OpenGL-based UI

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, user-interface, glsl

I'm planning to write a GL-based UI for one of the projects I'm currently working on. The majority of the UI will not be textured (just flat colors), but some elements need to support a single image. Elements only need to be scaled and translated - there are no complex animations or rotation needed. The UI will not neccessarily be static though - elements may appear/disappear during the lifetime of the application, and there are some cases where simple sliding animations are needed. Mouse over, clicked, selected etc states are also needed.

I'm trying to determine the best approach to manage and store the geometry for the UI elements themselves. My first thought was to create a single vertex buffer with one quad in it and use that quad for all UI draw calls. A transformation would be sent to the shader along with the quad of course.

Conventional wisdom suggests that minimizing state changes improves performance - a benefit of using a single VB.  However, there is the added cost of having to transform the quad for each UI element. Since the UI won't constantly be moving around, this seems a bit redundant.

On modern hardware, is it cheaper to transform the single quad, or does the cost of sending transformation data outweight the benefits only binding a single VB? Would I be better off maintaining separate geometry for each UI element, possibly computed on the CPU? Is there a different recommended approach commonly used by UI system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern hardware/drivers, the most expensive states to change are render target (FBO), shader (GLSL program) and texture. Vertex buffer (that is vertex attribute pointers, not the actual data) and uniform states are actually probably the cheapest states you would ever change between draw calls.

One of the things that makes draw calls expensive is all of the state validation that has to happen as a result of changed states, so it should come as no surprise that FBOs (which have perhaps the most complicated validation of anything in GL) are expensive and changing uniforms (which can pretty much be validated entirely before the call to `glUniform* (...)` returns) are cheap.

With that out of the way, assuming you are using the same textures and shaders for each of your UI elements, then changing a uniform or two and issuing another draw call is not going to be terribly expensive.

If you have enough small draw calls you could coalesce your transforms into a Uniform Buffer Object / Buffer Texture and then use some form of instancing to reduce this down to a single draw call. You will not see a measurable performance benefit from doing that unless the number of draw calls replaced is large enough; the point at which this becomes a practical optimization is hard to generalize. You can fool around with it if you want, but from the sounds of things you probably would not get anything useful out of it.

Instead, what you might consider doing is drawing your GUI into a texture. For frames when nothing in the GUI changes you can use the texture generated from a previous frame and skip any actual GUI compositing. When something does change, you can use stencil/scissor to clear only the "dirty" parts of the GUI and then re-draw them. Ultimately you would be stretching your GUI texture over the viewport every frame, the only difference is that on some frames you would be re-drawing some or all of that texture and on others you would reuse the entire thing.